# Django request data as parameters

Tags: python, django

Django has a QueryDict that contains request parameters which is accessed by `request.GET` or `request.POST`, I assumed that this data is filled based on the request type.

i.e If the request is GET then I need to use `request.GET`, if its post then use `request.POST`

But I noticed that regardless of request type (even PUT or DELETE) the data is available from `request.GET` but is always empty on `request.POST`

The method type is correct as I can check it using `request._get_request` which returns

```
<bound method WSGIRequest._get_request of <WSGIRequest: DELETE '/api/user/profile/'>>
```

Comment: HTTP protocol allows to send GET data in POST request and POST data in GET request. The same is with other types of requests.

Comment: So am I sending the request wrong ? I'm using Chrome's Postman plugin to specify the request type

Comment: I don't know . I  just want to say that in some APIs  GET/POST/PUT/DELETE request can send GET data (in url) and (in body as multipart data) POST data, JSON data and FILES .And it can send data also as Headers (Authorization: Bearer ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes are misnamed, really; they have nothing to do with GET and POST.

In HTTP, parameters can either be provided as the querystring part of the URL -  /foo/bar?q=123 - or in the request body. Django calls these GET and POST, but it's perfectly valid to have a querystring on a POST, hence the confusion. (The opposite isn't true, though; a GET can't have a body).